# jQuery UI: Animate the tabs of a horizontal navigation list without float attribute?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

```
<ul id="nav">
   <li>Tab 1</li>
   <li>Tab 2</li>
   <li>Tab 3</li>
</ul>

#nav li {
   display:inline-block;
   list-style:none;
}
```

This horizontal navigation menu uses `display:inline-block` to put them horizontal.  I want to animate the tabs so that one tab show up at a time on the screen in a horizontal fashion.

```
$("#nav li").hide().each(function(i) {
     $(this).delay(500*i).show("bounce", 2000);
});
```

However, this shows up one at a time vertically first before aligning them horizontally, which is not what I want.  Changing it to a floating list works, but I don't want to use that.  Is there anyway to animate the tabs with jQuery UI without needing to use the float attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Try animating their opacity...

```
<ul id="nav">
   <li>Tab 1</li>
   <li>Tab 2</li>
   <li>Tab 3</li>
</ul>

#nav li {
   display:inline-block;
   list-style:none;
   opacity: 0;
}
```

in the js

```
$("#nav li").each(function(i) {
   $(this).delay(500*i).animate({opacity: 1}, 2000, "bounce");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps adjusting the left position of your tabs is more suitable? Admittedly, it's a little bit more complicated, but it's not using `float` [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/A8hmt/1/).

It's basically done with a combination of `position: absolute` and adjusting the `left` value.

```
/*jQuery*/

$( "#nav li" ).each(function(i) {
   $(this).delay(500 * i).animate({ left: 80 * i}, 2000);
});

/*CSS*/
#nav {
   width: 240px;
   height: 40px;
   padding: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
   position: relative;
   background: rgba(111, 111, 111, .3);
}

#nav li {
   left: -60px;
   width: 60px;
   list-style: none;
   display: inline-block;
   background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
   padding: 10px;
   position: absolute;
   text-align: center;
}
```